# Adding multiple objects of same type into one

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing some C# coding where I have multiple objects of same type. For example:

```
public class Expense
{
    public decimal Food{ get; set; }
    public decimal Clothing{ get; set; }
    public decimal Medical{ get; set; }
}
```

Now we have `Expense` of 3 people X, Y and Z. I want to create an object "Total" of same type (`Expense`), which will add up all of these together.

Is there a shortcut to do this rather than adding all of them separately?

Comment: No, there is no shortcut.

Comment: When you say add "all of them separately" do you mean each property, or each object?

Comment: Not without using reflection. Create a method on Expense that returns the total of all expenses and use that in something like...persons.Sum(p => p.Expense.TotalExpenses());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have all your objects in a `List<>` (or other `IEnumerable`) then you can use Linq. For example, if your list is like this:

```
var X = new Expense { Food = 1, Clothing = 2, Medical = 3 };
var Y = new Expense { Food = 1, Clothing = 2, Medical = 3 };
var Z = new Expense { Food = 1, Clothing = 2, Medical = 3 };

var expenses = new List<Expense> { X, Y, Z };
```

You can create a 'total' expenses object by using the [`IEnumerable.Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298138(v=vs.100).aspx) method like this:

```
var totalExpenses = new Expense
{
    Food = expenses.Sum(e => e.Food),
    Clothing = expenses.Sum(e => e.Clothing),
    Medical = expenses.Sum(e => e.Medical)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a derived property

```
public class Expense
{
    public decimal Food{ get; set; }
    public decimal Clothing{ get; set; }
    public decimal Medical{ get; set; }
    public decimal TotalExpense { get { return Food+Clothing+Medical; } }
}
```

and then add up all the expenses

```
List<Expense> expenses = ...
decimal total = expenses.Sum((x)=>x.TotalExpense);
```

Comment: Why a new property instead of just `expenses.Sum((x)=>x.Food + x.Clothing + x.Medical)`?

Comment: Because you have a logical unit for `Expense` so with OOP principles let the object handle its own data. It just makes sense to me for every expense to have the total calculated locally. In the future if the expenses change you won't have to hunt all over the code to fix it. Keeping the calculation local means one change is going to be needed in the most obvious place, the `TotalExpense` property.